# Maven project as parent, gradle project as child

Tags: maven, gradle, parent-child, shared-module

I currently have a couple of maven modules within my maven parent module. I'd like to add a Gradle project as a module to that maven parent project. Is there any way to do this?

```
parent (maven)
 |-- back-end (maven)
 |-- front-end (gradle)   <-
 |-- shared (maven)
```

I use Kotlin in all modules. Also as gradle interpreter (build.gradle.kts) for front-end.

Comment: I think you can add a gradle project to an IDE by manually importing it. But it may not be possible to define a gradle project on a maven project structure. Maven and gradle does not have such kind of compatibility.

Comment: Why using Gradle? Use Maven for it as well.

Comment: Because Kotlin/JS (in combination with React) is only available for Gradle, and not for Maven.